# jQuery UI Draggable & Position simultaneously

Tags: jquery-ui, position, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to use jQuery UI Draggable Module and Position Widget simultaneously to create **Responsive** content.
However, I could not find any usage examples. I've created a simple **demo** => [jsfiddle.net/1ecg2jnc](http://jsfiddle.net/1ecg2jnc/)

**The problem is;** How do I **update** the **offset** of the elements when I **drag**.

```
<div class="element" 
     data-x="right" 
     data-y="top" 
     data-offset-x="-25" 
     data-offset-y="+45" >Draggable Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to the drag event which updates your offsets. Something like this:

```
$(this).draggable({
  containment: "#zone",
  cursor: 'move',
    drag: function(event, ui) { 
        $(event.target).data('offset-x', "+" + ui.offset.left);
        $(event.target).data('offset-y', "+" + ui.offset.top);
    }
});
```